# conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that The text property of UILabel is optional, I tried adding an else but i'm not sure what else to add.

productData.product.productName is me getting the name of the product from the database

```
            if var pName = productData.product.productName { //error
              self.productName.text = pName
            }

@IBOutlet weak var pName: UILabel!
```

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' is the error I get, It was working I think im not sure where its gone wrong

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `productData.product.productName` is not optional. Why have you tried to unwrap it?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri im trying to update the pName label with productName

Answer (score 0):

It states that the use of if condition is unnecessary, because the 'productName' is not optional.

You can directly add the value to your label.

```
self.productName.text = productData.product.productName //Product name is not optional
```

Optional chaining is used when you try to get a optional value.
For example, if you want to get the text of label then you'll require if condition.

```
if var text = self.productName.text { //Text in label is optional
   print(text)
}
```

Comment: so how do I updated the label with the productName?

Comment: Assigning the 'productData.product.productName' to the label will update the 'productName' to it.

Comment: so i tried pName = productData.product.productName and i get cannot assign string to UILabel error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the compiler is complaining that `productData.product.productName` is NOT an Optional. The `if var name = ____` construct only works on Optionals.

If you are testing for a non-empty String, you may want to check the `count` or `isEmpty` instead.